# Reading JSON in HDInsight pyspark from a blob storage

Tags: json, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to read a json file in HDInsight which is stored in a blob storage.
To operate on my cluster I am using a Jupyter notebook on pySpark 2.3 version.

Can someone help? All the commands I am getting is related to reading a CSV but not JSON.

Comment: spark.read.json should do it